# Extracting substrings ending with "mp4"

Tags: regex, match, preg-match-all

I have the following input:

```
string='GET........ref=mp4;GET........ref=flv;GET........ref=mp4;'
```

It has 3 segments. I need to extract the segments ending with `mp4;`.

ie.

```
GET........ref=mp4
GET........ref=mp4
```

The current result will match `GET........ref=mp4` and `GET........ref=flv;GET........ref=mp4;`.

My regular express: `GET(.*?)mp4`

I don't need the long match containing `flv` inside, and this regex does not work: `GET(.*?)(?!:flv)mp4`

I don't know how to solve and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your real string instead of a simplified string.

Answer (score 1):

You can explode the semi-colon separated list and then use `preg_grep` to get only the elements that end with `mp4`:

```
$string='GET........ref=mp4;GET........ref=flv;GET........ref=mp4;';
$res = explode(";", $string);
$res = preg_grep('/mp4$/i', $res);
print_r($res);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/IPwNMW)

If there are no semi-colons, all is glued:

```
// NO SEMI_COLONS
$str='GET........ref=mp4GET........ref=flvGET........ref=mp4';
preg_match_all('/GET\b(?:(?!GET\b).)*mp4(?=$|GET\b)/', $str, $res);
print_r($res);
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/EDAwgM)

Comment: actually, it doesn't have  a semi-colon between them, i just put them to easier to recognize the segments.

Comment: I added another answer in case you have all "GET" substrings glued together.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you need to split your string into tokens:

```
http://get........ref=mp4
http://get........ref=flv
http://get........ref=mp4
```

and then apply your regex. if you need it to start with the http and end with mp4 then use "^http.*mp4$"
The ^ means beginning of the line, $ means the end of the line and the .* means match any character 0 or more times. And example using sed to split the results for instance:

```
echo "http://get........ref=mp4;http://get........ref=flv;http://get........ref=mp4a;" | sed s/';'/\\n/g | grep "^http.*mp4$"
```

EDIT: if ';' is not your real separator, replace it with whatever is the real separator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for bit a cleaner approach that will work with or without `;`

```
preg_match_all("/GET(?:(?!GET).)*=mp4/", $str, $res);
print_r($res);
```